Anyone know why my glitch OAuth2 project is getting ratelimited?
I get a 429 status ratelimit whenever I try to connect to a bot.
I've tried three different bots (Like seriously, I made three bots) and it didn't work... I'm using discordjs v13.0.0 because glitch doesn't have a nodejs version which supports ReadableStream (breaks my project) 
Does anybody know what's happening? I've also tried using cached data instead of fetching data but it happens right when I try to use client.login. I've tried to debug it with many console outputs but it just gives me this 429 and "Server running on PORT 3000".

probably best to post your code.  rate limits in general are because you're trying to get a lot of data in a short amount of time.  Given the above...and you say it's ass soon as you login, best to post the code and let us help you further.

Alright.
My code doesn't fit here so I'll upload on Mediafire.
my code:
